# NDK: как получить dll

Tags: android-ndk, dll

Скачал NDK, там есть папка с примерами. Соответственно в каждой из этих папок есть директория jni, в которой лежит cpp файл и mk. Запускаю ndk-build, появляются несколько новых папок и как я понимаю статическая библиотека. Вопрос в том как получить динамическую .dll?

Comment: хорошо, как мне получить файл с расширением .so?

Comment: ndk-build все сделает, если нет ошибок. Поищите в каталогах. Хотя, если я правильно помню, то он сам разместит их где нужно (в каталоге libs) и потом они будут правильно включены в apk.

Answer (score 3):

Никак. Так как оно и не нужно - андроид не работает с `.dll`. Вам скорее всего нужны файлы с расширением `.so`.

Answer (score 2):

Android это Linux там нет DLL, а есть .so библиотеки

Кидает в папку libs/armeabi - для ARM процессоров и в libs/x86 - для Intel процессоров. Тип процессора задается в Application.mk - по умолчанию только для ARM

Comment: у меня в папке libs/armeabi только один файл и это вроде как не библиотека .so
правый клик->свойства показывает тип как "исполняемый(application/x-executable)"

Comment: все, проблема разрешилась, оказывается это задается в .mk файле